# Sharing Template emails in public folders

Tags: email, templates, microsoft-office-2003

I have a template email I've created and saved on my local templates folder. How do I share my template so anyone on my domain can use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Exchange Server you can publish it to the Organizational Forms Library in Exchange.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821922/

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/933358

Comment: Wonderful. Once the library is created in exchange, how to I add a template to it from outlook? fyi, I am using exchange server 2003 with outlook 2003